# Update Azure DevOps Wiki pages use powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

Please tell me how I can update (for example text) the Azure DevOps Wiki page using the Rest API and powershell. Maybe someone has a script to update the Wiki page. I can create Wiki Page and content use this powershell script.  For Example:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?path=SamplePage731&api-version=5.0"

$body = @"
    {
        "content": "test"
    }
"@

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

Error massage:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The page '/SamplePage129' specified in the add operation already 
>   exists in the wiki. Please specify a new page 
>   path.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server.WikiPageAlreadyExistsException, 
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server","typeKey":"WikiPageAlreadyExistsException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
>   At line:22 char:11
>   + $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -ContentType "appli ...
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: You can create but not update? what is the error, for the create of to the update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, apologize for our [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/Pages/Create%20Or%20Update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1) is not too clear, so that you got this error message.

According the code you shared, I found that you did not pass the **version** value of current page in the '**`If-Match`**' header along with your request.

This API requires **header** value to perform **UPDATE**. Without that, it will consider the operation as a "**ADD**" instead of an "**UPDATE**". That's why you got that error message. So, for update successfully, you need to provide the version in the header.

To get the 'version' of this page, just run a GET call to the page which you want to edit first. And then, the **`'ETag'`** value in the response header is the version you need to pass for the next UPDATE operation.

So, just modify your header content, add **If-Match** in it:

```
$headers = @{
 'Authorization' = ('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo) 
 'If-Match' = '{version}' 
}
```

**Edit:**
Since `$result` default content is response body, but `ETag` exists in response Headers. So you must need specified `Headers` to get it.

So, for how to use command to get this `ETag` in powershell, just use `$result.Headers.ETag` can achieve this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Could you please tell me what a command me need to execute in Powershell that I see this 'ETag'. Thanks and have a nice day)

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.